# Программный поворот изображения ip камеры по оси X и Y

Tags: python, камера

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как программно можно повернуть изображение ip камеры по осям x и y (иначе зеркалирование по осям)? Интересует поворот непосредственно на стороне камеры, а не на стороне просмотра потока. Подобный функционал реализован в CMS Polyvision.

[image: Чекбоксы для активации зеркалирования в CMS Polyvision]

Пробовал использовать onvif на python, однако, как оказалось, он не поддерживает данные операции.

Comment: Как я понимаю, для этого камера должна поддрерживать эти операции. Соответственно, должен быть API с таким функционалом. А программно залазить в камеру?.. Не представляю как это возможно. Revers Ingineering?

Comment: Но как тогда CMS Polyvision делает это? там просто необходимо зарегистрировать эти камеры и все. Далее, без дополнительных настроек, есть возможность переворачивать изображения. Может есть какой-нибудь механизм отправки управляющего пакета?

Comment: ну вот ваш polyvision, веороятно, как раз и использует API